# Mysql finding duplicates

Tags: mysql

have been given an assignment for school, things have been mostly going well but one query i must do has me stumped.  Here is a description of the two tables:

Movie: MovieId,[pk] Title, Year, DirectorCode[fk]

Director: DirectorCode,[pk] Name

What i have to do is find any directors that have remade their own movie, and display the Name of the movie, director's name and year of the first and second release??

even if you dont want to give me the answer I would be very greatful for some hints

Thanks

Comment: So, in search terms: find at least 2 years of a movie of which both Title and DirectorCode are the same. You might want to look at the `HAVING` clause for aggregates, and _if_ 3rd & 4th movie (etc.) also may be displayed, you can look at `GROUP_CONCAT`. If not (why not?), I'd still cheat & use `GROUP_CONCAT` in combination with a double `LOCATE` (to find the second separator) & `SUBSTRING` calls..

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the remake has a different movieId, but it will have the same title. Therefor you can find movies that has the same title and the same directorCode.

using GROUP BY and find all the movies that would have COUNT(title) > 1 would give you the directorCode and titles to search for, and then in a second query take out full info from both movies (first and second remake) using that, because the info would be lost in the GROUP BY. Another option would be to just select MAX(year), MIN(year) to find out the first and second year.

If you are allowed using "HAVING" keyword that will be useful in order to filter on a group by aggregate, however I don't remember if that is mysql proprietary or part of ANSI SQL.

Comment: just having an issue with doing the subquery, have ony done a few before.  got the outer query done fine though :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use having or a subquery, or even GROUP.  You can do this in one query as long as it is assumed that the movie and remake titles are identical.  Since they are remakes, I assume the titles will be identical with different years (otherwise, how can you identify a remake?  You would need another field).

```
SELECT
   name
   , m1.title
   , m1.year
   , m2.year as remake
FROM
   Movie m1
   JOIN Director d USING (directorcode)
   JOIN Movie m2 ON (
      d.directorcode = m2.directorcode
      AND m1.title = m2.title
      AND m1.year < m2.year
   )
```

The inner joins from Movie to Director and Director to Movie again ensure that you will only get results if the same director is on two movies.  Then, the titles are compared (this could also be done in the WHERE clause).  For organizational purposes, m1 is chosen to be less than m2 (also possible in the WHERE clause).  Otherwise, 'remake' could be the earlier one.

One thing to note is that if a director remakes a movie twice, you will get three rows.  E.g. if they remake a 2009 movie in 2010 and 2011, you will get a row where year = 2009, remake = 2010, year =  2009, remake = 2011, and year = 2010, remake = 2011.  From the context of the question, it seems like a director will only remake a movie once, though.

I tested this out and it will not show results for movies that have been remade by a different director or not at all.  If two directors remake the same movie twice (that's three remakes, two from a different director) you will get both of those directors.  I think this is desirable.

Comment: Nice approach, but how would this work with the third movie? Would m2 fields be from the second and third movie all in all?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by all in all or what you mean by third movie.  I assume that you are asking what will happen if a movie is remade twice.  I explained this in the answer: if it's remade twice, you'll get three rows indicating the three possible remake-year associations.  I also said that it probably doesn't even make sense for a director to remake the same movie twice anyway, at least from the context of the question.

Comment: Hm, if I read it correctly it will return 1 row if there is 1 remake, and if there are two remakes, you will get two rows, not three. Anyway, tomato, tomato. I find your answer to be the cleanest.